# Convert the String to JSON, getting by JQuery.Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, split

My php code produce something like that with this link `getPower.php?year=2012&country=tr`

```
"Kasan":[[1,50]]
"Tasan":[[1,51],[2,52],[3,52]]
"Hasan":[[1,50]]
"Masan":[[1,51],[2,52],[3,52]]
```

With this code;

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo json_encode($row['teamName']). ":" ;

putPowerbyTeam($db,$row['teamID'],$year); //End with echo "json_encode($returnArray);"  

echo "\n";
```

And I'm trayin to convert them into JavaScript Object with this code;

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
url: "getPower.php",
data: {year : "year", country : "country"},
success: function(JSONText) {

    var lines = JSONText.split('\n');

    $.each(lines,function(lineNo,line)
                    {
        var mainItems = line.split(':');
        chart.series[lineNo].name = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(mainItems[0]));
        chart.series[lineNo].setData(jQuery.parseJSON(eval(mainItems[1])), true);
    });

},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}
```

I'm an error which say cannot split the null. So, null is returned but i can't be sure any part of this javascrip code.

So, why null is returned?
What can i do?
Is the rest is good?

Comment: Is your JSON even valid ? Paste the output [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to build your JSON with multiple `echo` and `json_encode`. Use one big associative array and then `echo json_encode(array)`.

Something like this :

```
$array = array();

$teamName = $row['teamName'];

$array[$teamName] = putPowerbyTeam($db,$row['teamID'],$year); // Return the array instead of doing json_encode($returnArray);

echo json_encode(array);
```

Comment: If I take all data with an array, I have a problem with "chart.series[lineNo].setData" it only wants data, i should seperate the name and data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dataType` like this :

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
url: "getPower.php",
data: {year : "year", country : "country"},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(JSONText) {

// do something
```